# I can not insert any picture on the site

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

i can't see any picture im my projects, here is what happens

[image]

i am using gulp, here is a gulpfile, but for some reason every picture in my projects without gulp  also are not shown, they just dissapeared and i don't know why. i don't know what to do with that, pls help me
P.S sorry if i have mistakes in my english.

```
let source_folder = "#src";
let fs = require('fs');
let path = {
   build: {
      html: project_folder + "/",
      css: project_folder + "/css/",
      js: project_folder + "/js/",
      img: project_folder + "/img/",
      fonts: project_folder + "/fonts/",
   },
   src: {
      html: [source_folder + "/*.html", "!" + source_folder + "/_*.html"],
      css: source_folder + "/scss/style.scss",
      js: source_folder + "/js/script.js",
      img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|webp)",
      fonts: source_folder + "/fonts/*.ttf",
   },
   watch: {
      html: source_folder + "/**/*.html",
      css: source_folder + "/scss/**/*.scss",
      js: source_folder + "/js/**/*.js",
      img: source_folder + "/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|ico|svg|webp)",
   },
   clean: "./" + project_folder + "/"
}
let { src, dest } = require("gulp"),
   gulp = require("gulp"),
   browsersync = require("browser-sync").create(),
   fileinclude = require("gulp-file-include"),
   del = require("del"),
   autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
   scss = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass')),
   group_media = require('gulp-group-css-media-queries'),
   clean_css = require('gulp-clean-css'),
   rename = require('gulp-rename'),
   uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default,
   imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
   webp = require('gulp-webp'),
   webphtml = require('gulp-webp-html'),
   webpcss = require('gulp-webpcss'),
   svgSprite = require('gulp-svg-sprite'),
   ttf2woff = require('gulp-ttf2woff'),
   ttf2woff2 = require('gulp-ttf2woff2'),
   fonter = require('gulp-fonter')


function browserSync() {
   browsersync.init({
      server: {
         baseDir: "./" + project_folder + "/"
      },
      port: 3000,
      notify: false
   })
}

function html() {
   return src(path.src.html)
      .pipe(fileinclude())
      .pipe(webphtml())
      .pipe(dest(path.build.html))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}



function images() {
   return src(path.src.img)
      .pipe(webp({
         quality: 70,

      }))
      .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
      .pipe(src(path.src.img))
      .pipe(
         imagemin([
            imagemin.gifsicle({ interlaced: false }),
            imagemin.mozjpeg({ progressive: true }),
            imagemin.optipng({ optimizationLevel: 3 }),
            imagemin.svgo({
               plugins: [
                  { removeViewBox: false },
               ]
            })
         ]))
      .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}


function js() {
   return src(path.src.js)
      .pipe(fileinclude())
      .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(
         rename({
            extname: ".min.js"
         })
      )
      .pipe(dest(path.build.js))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())

}

function css() {
   return src(path.src.css)
      .pipe(scss({ outputStyle: 'expanded' }).on('error', scss.logError))
      .pipe(
         group_media()
      )
      .pipe(
         autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist: ['last 5 versions'],
            cascade: true
         })
      )
      .pipe(webpcss({ webpClass: '.webp', noWebpClass: '.no-webp' }))
      .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
      .pipe(
         clean_css()
      )
      .pipe(
         rename({
            extname: ".min.css"
         })
      )
      .pipe(dest(path.build.css))
      .pipe(browsersync.stream())
}

function fonts() {
   src(path.src.fonts)
      .pipe(ttf2woff())
      .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts))
   return src(path.src.fonts)
      .pipe(ttf2woff2())
      .pipe(dest(path.build.fonts))
}

gulp.task('otf2ttf', function () {
   return src([source_folder + '/fonts/*.otf'])
      .pipe(fonter({
         formats: ['ttf']
      }))
      .pipe(dest(source_folder + '/fonts/'))
})


gulp.task('svgSprite', function () {
   return gulp.src([source_folder + '/iconsprite/*.svg'])
      .pipe(svgSprite({
         mode: {
            stack: {
               sprite: "../icons/icons.svg",
               example: true
            }
         },
      }
      ))
      .pipe(dest(path.build.img))
})

function fontsStyle() {
   let file_content = fs.readFileSync(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss');
   if (file_content == '') {
      fs.writeFile(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss', '', cb);
      return fs.readdir(path.build.fonts, function (err, items) {
         if (items) {
            let c_fontname;
            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
               let fontname = items[i].split('.');
               fontname = fontname[0];
               if (c_fontname != fontname) {
                  fs.appendFile(source_folder + '/scss/fonts.scss', '@include font("' + fontname + '", "' + fontname + '", "400", "normal");\r\n', cb);
               }
               c_fontname = fontname;
            }
         }
      })
   }
}

function cb() {

}

function watchFiles() {
   gulp.watch([path.watch.html], html);
   gulp.watch([path.watch.css], css);
   gulp.watch([path.watch.js], js);
   gulp.watch([path.watch.img], images);
}

function clean() {
   return del(path.clean)
}

let build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(js, css, html, images, fonts), fontsStyle);
let watch = gulp.parallel(build, watchFiles, browserSync);



exports.fontsStyle = fontsStyle;
exports.js = js;
exports.fonts = fonts;
exports.images = images;
exports.css = css;
exports.html = html;
exports.build = build;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.default = watch;
```

Answer (score 1):

`#` isn't a valid character in an URL (unless you are referring to a [fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment), which you aren't). It may work, if you escape it as `%23` (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), but it would be better, not to use it at all.